# Outbound link tracking - Google Analytics' _trackEvent() and Omniture's s.tl()

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events, adobe-analytics

We have a site that uses both Omniture and Google Analytics. Ideally, we want to report in both suites on clicks to outbound links.

I'd like to do this the "right way," i.e. overcoming the race condition that occurs when requesting a site and the tracking pixel at the same time. See: http://www.gwotricks.com/test/2009/07/tracking-outbound-links-right-way.html

I probably wouldn't use the "onclick" attribute, instead binding the trackEvent to the link's click event.

Omniture's external link tracking overcomes the condition by hooking a 500ms delay into `s.tl()`:

www. webmetric.org/white_paper/link_tracking.pdf

Has anyone tried doing both on the same site? Ideally I'd like to call both tracking pixels with an appropriate amount of time before the page executes, but I'm not a big enough Omniture buff to really have gone in-depth with their code and hook trackEvent in before the delay.

Comment: not really sure what your question is...are you asking how to hook a click even to a link?

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript DOM (or if you use it, jQuery) to bind the events and utilize the new asynchronous Google Analytics tracking code and you should be set.

Sample codes for JavaScript event binders are everywhere if you don't want to use jQuery.

Done this several times, never interfered and never had to use a timer.

Comment: But the nature of the asynchronous request means that the user could theoretically get to the next page BEFORE the request is made to Google's tracking pixel, in which case the event would never be tracked. The 500 ms delay that omniture uses ensures that almost all of the time, the request is at least made to their servers before the next page responds.

Comment: According to my understanding the GA asynchronous code works nicely with this, I haven't seen a case where this is an issue with GA. Your browser most likely never receives a reply from Google before the next page, but that's not required for a successful record. If you would like, you could build a binder has a both GA and SiteCatalyst link binding. This of course means you should disable the default link tracking from Omniture to avoid duplicates.